# Failure joining on-prem to Azure DSC Automation (Response code: Unauthorized)

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I'm having difficulties joining a Windows machine to Azure DSC automation. I'm getting the following error:

```
Registration of the Dsc Agent with the server https://azureserver/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX failed. The underlying error is: The attempt to register Dsc Agent with AgentId
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX with the server https://azureserver/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Nodes(AgentId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') returned unexpected response code
Unauthorized. .
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterDscAgentUnsuccessful,Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.Commands.RegisterDscAgentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : AZURE-TEST
```

Here is my meta mof config

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$RegistrationUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$RegistrationKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName,

        [Int]$RefreshFrequencyMins = 30,

        [Int]$ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins = 15,

        [String]$ConfigurationMode = "ApplyAndMonitor",

        [String]$NodeConfigurationName

)

[DscLocalConfigurationManager()]
Configuration DscMetaConfigs
{

    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$RegistrationUrl,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$RegistrationKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName,

        [Int]$RefreshFrequencyMins = 30,

        [Int]$ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins = 15,

        [String]$ConfigurationMode = "ApplyAndMonitor",

        [String]$NodeConfigurationName,

        [Boolean]$RebootNodeIfNeeded= $False,

        [String]$ActionAfterReboot = "ContinueConfiguration",

        [Boolean]$AllowModuleOverwrite = $False,

        [Boolean]$ReportOnly = $False
    )

    if(!$NodeConfigurationName -or $NodeConfigurationName -eq "")
    {
        $ConfigurationNames = $null
    }
    else
    {
        $ConfigurationNames = @($NodeConfigurationName)
    }

    if($ReportOnly)
    {
    $RefreshMode = "PUSH"
    }
    else
    {
    $RefreshMode = "PULL"
    }

    Node $ComputerName
    {

        Settings
        {
            RefreshFrequencyMins = $RefreshFrequencyMins
            RefreshMode = $RefreshMode
            ConfigurationMode = $ConfigurationMode
            AllowModuleOverwrite = $AllowModuleOverwrite
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $RebootNodeIfNeeded
            ActionAfterReboot = $ActionAfterReboot
            ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins = $ConfigurationModeFrequencyMins
        }

        if(!$ReportOnly)
        {
        ConfigurationRepositoryWeb AzureAutomationDSC
            {
                ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
                RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
                ConfigurationNames = $ConfigurationNames
            }

            ResourceRepositoryWeb AzureAutomationDSC
            {
            ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
            RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
            }
        }

        ReportServerWeb AzureAutomationDSC
        {
            ServerUrl = $RegistrationUrl
            RegistrationKey = $RegistrationKey
        }
    }
}

DscMetaConfigs -RegistrationUrl $RegistrationUrl -RegistrationKey $RegistrationKey -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -NodeConfigurationName $NodeConfigurationName
```

I have a script that allows an end user to put in the necessary information (Registration keys, URL etc..), generates the meta mof then feeds it to the LCM. But I get the aforementioned error when I try to execute.

Here is the relevant DSC event error log

```
Job {6E7C0C83-BD69-11E7-BD75-005056852B86} : 
Http Client XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX failed for WebReportManager for configuration 
FullyQualifiedErrorId :ReportManagerSendStatusReportUnsuccessful
 CategoryInfo:InvalidResult: (:) [], InvalidOperationException
 ExceptionMessage:The attempt to send status report to the server https://azureserver/accounts/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Nodes(AgentId='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')/SendReport returned unexpected response code Unauthorized.
, InnerException
.
```

Does anybody have any ideas on what could be the problem? Given the error I'm assuming it's permissions/authentication related, but I'm not sure what it could besides the key, which I've double checked to make sure is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and finally I found a solution.

### tldr;

Delete all various `DSC-Oaas` certificates on the server (using Powershell):

```perl
 gci cert: -Recurse | where friendlyname -eq "DSC-OaaS Client Authentication" | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

Then register the server to Azure Automation.

### Explaination

Looking through the DSC logs in EventViewer, I found some entries that looked interesting. Notice the `Job` identifier.

[image: Log level Error]

Looking further down the list of entries, making sure to look at entries with the same `Job` identifier, I found an entry telling me which certificate was used in the communication to Azure Automation:

[image: Log level Information]

I located the certificate in the local machine certificate store, together with a bunch of other similar certificates.

[image: Found the cert]

[image: All certificates]

When I deleted all certificates with `friendlyname = DSC-OaaS Client Authentication`

```perl
gci cert: -Recurse | where friendlyname -eq "DSC-OaaS Client Authentication" | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

..and registred the server successfully to Azure Automation.

Answer (score 0):

You could get Registration keys, URL on Azure Portal.

[image]

More information please refer to this [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding#physicalvirtual-windows-machines-on-premises-or-in-a-cloud-other-than-azureaws).

Comment: Please ensure [WMF 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616) is installed.

Comment: The machine is Windows 10, and has Powershell 5.1 installed. And I'm using the primary access key from the page you mentioned. Unfortunately, I've been getting that error though. Are there any other reasons for that error to occur?

Comment: @JohnDoe Do you try this [config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding#generating-dsc-metaconfigurations).

Comment: The config in the link is the one I've been using. It appears to work on some machines but it doesn't work on a specific set of machines within a specific subnet. The strange part is that there are no ACL for any traffic going out from there. Still investigating.

Comment: @JohnDoe Do you have some firewall rules in your VM? For test, could you disable firewall and test again.

Comment: It works sometimes, and other times it doesn't work. It's fairly variable. I might test it on the same system, it runs fine. Test it again in 10 minutes, it'll fail. And even when it fails with the error I mentioned before, I'll observe at times that the server will actually still join to Azure and pull it's configuration. I've eliminated the network, and the script as being the culprits since I've even tested it by logging in on the machine via my Azure account on Powershell and pulling the metamof that needs to be run.